# Installing Elementary OS on Mac Pro 1,1 (black screen on after boot screen)

Tags: boot

I'm new to linux, i'm trying to install Elementary OS on my Mac Pro, I get the 'elementary os' boot screen and the count down from 10 seconds but when I allow the operation to boot - it just goes to a black screen resulting in me restarting or shutting down the system.

I've also tried booting using 'f10' which yielded the same result.

Can I boot elementary using the command line?

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Apologies if this has been asked before.

**EDIT: so I tried the following thank you for the suggestions but again im not sure if i've done something wrong[image]**

Steve

Comment: Add nomodeset to grub. Press F10 during boot, hit the alt button, and add 'nomodeset' and see if that gets you a screen you can see.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add "noefi" after "splash" at the end of the line. And you need to use a pc keyboard to press f10 otherwise it wont work. God luck.

Answer (score 0):

The MacPro1,1 uses a 32-bit EFI which appears to be where the problems come in.
A great resource is [this post](https://mattgadient.com/linux-dvd-images-and-how-to-for-32-bit-efi-macs-late-2006-models/) on mattgradient.com.
If you're able to burn a DVD there is a prebuilt elementary OS 5.1 Hera image available.
I can't attest to whether you should trust the ISO images from the site or not, but instructions for modding existing ISO's yourself are provided.

You might also find [this Debian Wiki page](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Apple/MacPro/1-1) for installing on the MacPro1,1 useful though it is a bit sparse.